# How can I install Messages.app on Lion

Tags: macos, messages

Is there any way to get the final version of Messages.app installed on Lion?  For reasons I'll not get into at this point upgrading to Mountain Lion is not possible.  I had the beta of Messages.app but removed it because it was buggy.

Is there any way to install the 1.0 version on Lion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: **The final build of Messages isn't available for Lion. It is only available on Mountain Lion.**

MacRumors had [an article](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/06/12/apple-removes-links-to-messages-beta-for-os-x-lion-still-available-via-direct-link/) on this:

> Apple has not removed the download entirely, however, as it is still
>   accessible via [direct download (63.8 MB)](http://appldnld.apple.com/MessagesBeta/041-4274.20120216.z5km/MessagesBeta.dmg)

You can also download it via [Mac Update.](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/41878/apple-messages)

Comment: Thats still the beta.  I want the Final version

Comment: @dstarh oh. The final build of Messages isn't available for Lion. It is only available on Mountain Lion.

Comment: yea that was sort of the whole point of the question

Comment: Well, there's your answer. Sorry to disappoint you...

Comment: if you update your answer to say it's not available I'll accept it